# How to automate graph display for large datasets?

Tags: plotting, graphics, function-construction

Large outputs are automatically truncated. For example,

[image]

How can I apply this to displaying graphs?

```
myLongGraphs = Plot[1 + #  x/(  x - 1), {x, 0, 5}] & /@ Range[20000]
```

For instance, I need to plot 20,000 graphs, but displaying all of them at once would cause my PC to freeze or crash. How can I display, for example, 1000 graphs at a time, click something to view another 1000, and continue in this manner? Additionally, I want to save the results of all 20,000 graphs in the variable `myLongGraphs`.
I understand that I could manually divide the plotting into smaller sizes, but I'm actually looking for a more automated solution.

Comment: Make myLongGraphs an array, then you can display one row at a time.

Comment: @DanielHuber do you have any example or tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified example. Assume you have a long list:

```
ll= Range[100];
```

Cut this into pieces and assign them to an array:

```
arr = Partition[ll, 10];
```

Now you can display every piece separately:

```
arr[[2]]

{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}
```

Or more convenient:

```
DynamicModule[{i}, 
 Column[{SetterBar[Dynamic[i], Range[10]], Dynamic@arr[[ i]]}]]
```

[image]